# Examples of firms having private information about negative event

Tags: asymmetric-information

as the title says, I am searching for examples where a firm incurs a negative event, for instance, a stockout, a supply chain glitch or investments that went wrong. In the best case the firm was in the aftermath under financial distress or even had to file for bankruptcy as a consequence of that initially privately known event.

If you have a link to an example or just remember firm names, it would be a great help.

Best wishes
Paul

Answer (score 3):

Banks that were not bailed out in the 2008 recession and went insolvent i.e. Washington Mutual, IndyMac, Franklin Bank, First National Bank of Nevada e.t.c. You could also look into firms that were sanctioned by the Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC). I do not know the names of the top of my head but a simple google search should suffice.

Comment: Hi Rumi, thank you for your answer. Do you or someone else know of any event where a supplier or manufacturer has had a internal failure that led to serious losses which it decided to not reveal in fear of disadvantages?

Comment: Yahoo breach where they did not disclose the breach until several years later. Target in 2013 and Home Depot in 2014.

Comment: Thank you, Rumi. Yahoo was great